# joing 2 tables creates unwanted duplicate data

Tags: sql, join

I'm having trouble figuring out how to join 2 tables. 
I just want to have 1 column from another table joined but adding this creates a lot of duplicate data in the table.

First table: "devices":

```
id | device_type | open_ticket_count | device_owner 
1  | tablet      | 1                 | bob
2  | smartphone  | 0                 | 
3  | printer     | 1                 | sally
```

Second table: "tickets":

```
id | due_at
1  | 25/12/2016
2  | 
3  | 13/11/2016
```

I want to join them so it's like this:

```
id | device_type | open_ticket_count | device_owner | due_at
1  | tablet      | 1                 | bob          | 25/12/2016
2  | smartphone  | 0                 |              |
3  | printer     | 1                 | sally        | 13/11/2016
```

How would I do that?

This code is creating 292 rows but there's only 3 devices and 2 tickets open?

```
SELECT devices.id, devices.device_type, devices.open_ticket_count, devices.primary_owner_name AS Assigned_Owner, tickets.id, tickets.due_at 

FROM devices CROSS JOIN tickets where devices.user_tag = '|pool devices|' AND tickets.due_at
```

Any ideas on how to just show

All the devices with the due_at column?

Comment: Use `inner join` rather than `cross join`.

Comment: I'm SORRY, how do I edit the title of my post? (up late trying to get this to work and made a typo!)

Comment: Thanks, that is getting 292 Rows also using INNER JOIN?

Comment: How are the tables supposed to be related?

Comment: When you converted it to INNER JOIN,  what was your ON condition?

Comment: Thanks INNER JOIN is only outputting 112 Rows now for this:

Comment: SELECT devices.device_type, devices.open_ticket_count, devices.primary_owner_name AS Assigned_Owner, tickets.due_at 

FROM devices INNER JOIN tickets where devices.user_tag = '|pool devices|' AND tickets.due_at AND tickets.status = 'open'

Comment: Is the id field in tickets meant to be the id of the associated device?

Comment: You are not using a join condition at all.

Comment: I am pretty lost here, the two tables have the id column I thought you could only join two tables with a common column name.

Comment: You can join tables on any columns, but you need to specify what they are in the join condition (`ON`). Some flavours of SQL have a 'natural' join which does this automatically though. So we are a little confused also because you haven't specified what type of SQL (SQL Server, MySQL, Oracle etc.). Please add a tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT D.id, D.device_type, D.open_ticket_count, D.device_owner, T.due_at 
FROM Devices D LEFT OUTER JOIN Tickets T 
ON D.id = T.id
```

You want to display all rows from the column at Left, so you need **LEFT OUTER JOIN**.

Answer (score 0):

Andy, try

```
SELECT devices.id, devices.device_type, devices.open_ticket_count, devices.device_owner AS Assigned_Owner, tickets.due_at
FROM devices INNER JOIN tickets
ON devices.id = tickets.id
WHERE due_at IS NOT NULL
```

although this assumes that the `tickets.due_at` column will be `null` for the row where `id = 2`

But you would get the same result if you excluded rows in the devices table that had an `open_ticket_count = 0` (assuming that this is zero if there are no matching **ticket** rows

Comment: Thanks for the help so far, the LEFT OUTER JOIN and the INNER JOIN is producing a lot less rows, but still too many.

Comment: is there a way of selecting only devices in a particular group called "|pool devices|"

Comment: i tried using WHERE devices.user_tag = '|pool devices|' but it didn't work.